# What's the recommended approach for getting lists for multiple selections and displaying them in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've searched both SO and Google on this but have not found a relevant / acceptable answer.
Background:
 * Using MVC 4.5
 * I have some Generic `Repo<T>` that I am using over the top of EF5, which in turn are accessed by generic `Service<T>`
 * I have domain models and view models and I am using Automapper to map between them, this mapping happens in the `Service` layer
 * On top of that, I have my `Controllers` which again are generic as much as possible.

So, to the question; I have a couple of scenarios where I need to present a list of options to the user and they have to select one or more. The options are user specific, so my domain `User` has a `List<Location>` which is their saved locations, and when adding / modifying, an `Item`, they are required to select at least one `Location`.

I am resisting the temptation to fetch that `List<Location>` in my controllers because I want to keep them generic and slim, but at the same time, I'd rather not have two properties in my `ItemView` model, one for `AvailableLocations` and one for `SelectedLocations`, because this model is used not just for adding / modifying but for search results etc.

Options:
* Should I introduce a different model for adding / modifying an `Item`, e.g. `ItemInput`?
* Should I use some custom mapping and get Automapper to get the list of available locations?
* In which layer should I fetch these available locations?

What are people's suggestions on a neat and generic approach to this please?
Many thanks!

Comment: What is the role of your generic services (I mean, how are they *generic*)?

Comment: The service layer knows what domain model maps to what view model, so it is responsible for calling the correct repo then mapping to view models. This is all done generically, e.g. Service <TDomain,  TView>

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like this:

```
    public IEnumerable<Location> GetLocations() {
        return db.GetAll();
    }
```

Then inside of your controller (I followed this from MVC scaffolding):

```
 ViewBag.Locations = new SelectList(service.GetLocations, "name", "id");
```

(or your own checkbox list)
and put a listing control on the HTML/View page.

The reason I believe this is the best method is because the logic all resides inside the service. If you put it in your DTO/data model you may come against this problem:

What happens if you require additional logic to pull back locations? i.e. sub locations of locations.

You change your service (or override) to reflect the new changes, and this logic would go inside of the service:

```
    public IEnumerable<Location> GetLocations(string parent) {
        return db.GetAll().Where(loc => loc.parentname = parent);
    }
```

p.s. I never use generic services, the reason I have a service is because some of the data access it provides contains logic that is not meant to sit with the generic DAL.

I could make an interface or abstract service to make my life a little easier for common operations between services but once you define say a concrete, a `UserManagementSerive` surely you are saying you want to manage an object that has Users, and Locations and Items each having its own specific functionality?

Comment: Thanks @Smithy; I'd rather not use ViewBag as its not type safe. Doing it this way also means manually binding the results of the selection back to my model, whereas MVC should be doing that for me automatically. There must be a neater solution, surely?

Comment: @Simon actually, if you have say User.LocationID in your User model definition and you call your say Html.DropDownList("LocationID") populated via ViewBag.LocationID = new selectlist... it will automatically do the bind for you.

Comment: I have also seen methods for binding multiple values for if Locations was an array of Location object also

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is only one possible answer to this question.

I would recommend a simple, but not-so-generic approach. I would write what's called *ViewModels*, i.e. model classes that are related to your specific views. Then I would get your available locations from the controller, and populate an instance of the ViewModel in your controller using the fetched locations.

Basically I would expose some services like:

```
IEnumerable<Location> GetAvailableLocationsForUser(string userName);
```

Do note I've used `IEnumerable<T>`, not `IQueryable<T>`. Because the implementation will actually request the database, as it's too much bug-prone (at least IMO) if it's the role of the controller to do so (remember the deferred execution of `IQueryable<T>`).
And it returns a domain instance, i.e. an entity, not a mapped model. I wouldn't personally deal with anything but domain classes in the service layer. There could be domain classes that are **not** entities, but compositions of entities for example. This could help making efficient requests and avoiding using lazy-loading and deferred execution in the controllers. This is helpful when the controller needs a whole object graph and not only an entity.

Then I would write Models and ViewModels like the following, in the web application assembly:

```
public LocationModel
{
    ...
}

public CreateItemViewModel : ItemModel
{
    public List<LocationModel> AssociatedLocations { get; set; }
    public List<LocationModel> AvailableLocations { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

- There are basically *Models* (`ItemModel` and `LocationModel`), which are objects related to the web application. This means there could be some web-related things in those models, for example computed read-only properties or attributes on properties (`DisplayAttribute`...etc.).
  I would write those models multiple times, actually, because I don't think this is something that could be generalized: for example, one view could require the use of a navigation property while another view wouldn't. So this changes the depth of the mapping process depending on the views that uses the model. And I wouldn't use AutoMapper at all (only hand-written mappers).
- There are also *ViewModels* (`CreateItemViewModel`), which are objects related to a **single** view (for example the view that allows to create an Item in this example). The difference between Model and ViewModel is that the ViewModel is related to a single view (and named according to this view). On the other hand, Models are related to multiple views (its namespace would help to know which views. For example, `xxx.Item.Models` for Models related to all views in the `xxx.Item` directory). ViewModels are built from scratch in the controller (or in a separate mapper) based on the domain classes.

In the above example, you *could* build a domain classes that would return `AssociatedLocations` and `AvailableLocations`, but it would require your service layer to be aware of the web part (I mean, your service interface and domain classes would know which properties are needed for a particular view). I'm not sure those properties are actually related to a single view in your application, but if it's not the case, you could also build a domain class as a composition of entities that would return `AssociatedLocations` and `AvailableLocations`:

```
public ItemExtended : Item
{
    public List<Location> AssociatedLocations { get; set; }
    public List<Location> AvailableLocations { get; set; }
}

ItemExtended GetItemExtendedById(long idItem);
```